# How to make a GIS query on PostgreSQL without use ST_X("Position4326") function

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have written this geographical query:

```
SELECT
    ST_X("Position4326") AS lon,
    ST_Y("Position4326") AS lat,
    "Values"[4] AS ppe,
    "Values"[5] AS speed
FROM
(
SELECT
  *
FROM
  "SingleData"

UNION ALL

SELECT
  *
FROM
  "SingleDataOld"
) AS d
WHERE
  "Values"[5] > 0
```

and its work.

But I would like to select a specific area in the database, e.g.:

```
Lat_min = 43.77;
Lat_max = 43.88;
Lon_min = 12.95;
Lon_max = 13.05;
```

to reduce the time of working.

It is possible do this **without** use `ST_X` and `ST_Y` function? Or, better: I would like use a `WHERE` clause, but the format of geographical data are `Position4326`, an alphanumeric string that I do not know how manipulate.

Comment: So you're using postgis, right?

Comment: Yes, PostGIS, but I do not able to use it in deep. I follow another part of this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of position4326 could be of geometry type or [geography](http://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography) type. Postgis offer a big range of functions which you can use to limit the result data improve the performance.

I.e. use can the function [ST_MakeEnvelope](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeEnvelope.html) and the [&&](http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) operator:

```
WHERE ...
AND Position4326 && ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, srid);
```

in latitude/longitude terms, the arguments are so:

```
ST_MakeEnvelope(long_min, lat_min, long_max, lat_max, srid);
```

Because you column is named Position4326, I guess you should use srid = 4326.

```
ST_MakeEnvelope(12.95, 43.77, 13.05, 43.88, 4326);
```

Also ensure that you have a [spatial index](http://revenant.ca/www/postgis/workshop/indexing.html) on the column Position4326:

```
CREATE INDEX Position4326_gix ON your_table USING GIST (Position4326);
```

Comment: Thanks Tommaso, the command `ST_MakeEnvelope` it is what I was looking for.